# Is there any way to prevent a .NET app using the new csproj format from living in bin/debug/net472/AppName?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, csproj

It used to be in /bin/debug/AppName but now there's this new net472 folder ever since I upgraded to the new cspproj format. Any way to switch it back without downgrading the csproj files?

Comment: Do you mean the output folder?  You can change that in the IDE under Debug -> Build output path.  Or in the `.csproj` under `OutputPath`

Comment: I did change the output folder to bin/debug but it still created the net472 subfolder.

Answer (score 3):

This is a rather old post but, since I was looking for this answer and knew there are some XML attributes that can be added to the csproj file, th following may be helpful:

```
<AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath>false</AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath>
```

and

```
<AppendRuntimeIdentifierToOutputPath>false</AppendRuntimeIdentifierToOutputPath>
```